# php-mysql alternative function of rollback

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as author and book. I want to insert data from author table to book table.
If insert is successfully then the data of author table will be deleted , if not successes then data will not be deleted from author table.
I want to use Rollback but here author and book are two different databases in different server.
Any building function are exist in php and mysql that i can do that.

Comment: Are the two databases both InnoDB?

Comment: What code have you written so far? Show the code so we can help you.

Comment: yes.two databases are both InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

First insert all rows from author table  to book table

```
   insert into database1.book (fields_BookTable) 
   select fields_aAuthor_inBookTable from database2.author
```

then check using id field if data has been inserted into book table

```
delete from database2.author where id in (select id from database1.book);
```

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are isolated within a single "database".

What you should really do is, use a single database connection to use both databases.

In MySQL, "database" is really more like a "catalog" or "schema" in other servers. You can use tables from another database in the same connection as permissions allow.

For managing transactions via PHP (untested):

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());  
$objDB = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");  

//*** Start Transaction ***//  
mysql_query("BEGIN");

$query = "query1 comes here...";    

if( mysql_query($query) )  {  
   // Commit Transaction  
   mysql_query("COMMIT");  
   echo "Save Done.";  
}  
else  {  
   // RollBack Transaction
   mysql_query("ROLLBACK");  
   echo "Error Save [".$strSQL."]";  
}  
mysql_close($objConnect);
```

And check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: Here , database exist are two different server

Answer (score 0):

A solution controlled by PHP, assuming the `mysql` extension and a numeric PK column (**NB** you would only do this if you absolutely cannot wrap it in a transaction, for example if there were two different servers):

```
// Server connections
$srcConn = mysql_connect('somewhere', 'user', 'pass');
$dstConn = mysql_connect('elsewhere', 'user', 'pass');

// Fetch data to move into an array
$query = "
  SELECT *
  FROM `srcdb`.`table`
";
$result = mysql_query($query, $srcConn);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $data[] = $row;
mysql_free_result($result);

// Rows to handle per cycle
// A larger number reduces the number queries, but you need to respect the MySQL
// max_allowed_packet and it will also increase PHP memory usage
$rowsPerCycle = 100;

// Name of the primary key column
$pKName = 'id';

// This will hold the column names in the right order, without the PK
// You could make the list static if you know what it will be
// You may also need to keep the PK value
$colNames = array();
foreach ($data[0] as $colName => $val) {
  if ($colName != $pKName) { // Remove me if you need to keep the PK values
    $colNames[] = $colName;
  }
}

// Keep looping while $data still has some elements
while ($data) {

  // Remove $rowsPerCycle elements from the beginning of $data
  $cycleData = array_splice($data, 0, $rowsPerCycle);

  // This array holds a list of the primary keys we are migrating
  $cycleIds = array();

  // Build the base query
  $query = "
    INSERT INTO `destdb`.`table`
      (`".implode("`, `", $colNames)."`)
    VALUES
  ";

  // Loop the rows and append them to the query (after escaping them, of course...)
  foreach ($cycleData as $row) {
    $cycleIds[] = $row[$pKName];
    unset($row[$pKName]); // Remove me if you need to keep the PK values
    $query .= "\n('" . implode("', '", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $row, array_fill(0, count($row), $dstConn)) . "'),";
  }

  // Do the insert
  if (!mysql_query($query, $dstConn)) {
    // Handle insert errors here
    trigger_error('MySQL Error: '.mysql_error($dstConn).'; Query: '.$query);
  }

  // Do the delete
  $query = "
    DELETE FROM `srcdb`.`table`
    WHERE `$pKName` IN (".implode(', ', $cycleIds).")
  ";
  if (!mysql_query($query, $srcConn)) {
    // Handle insert errors here
    trigger_error('MySQL Error: '.mysql_error($srcConn).'; Query: '.$query);
  }

}
```